# Кэшированный ОЗУ

Tags: windows, ram

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот у меня 3 GB ОЗУ.Всего 2804. Кэшировано 1130. доступно только 1642 а еще и свободно 642. Это только антивирус Avast работала(без никаких программ компютер запущено и антивирус и все).В чем проблема?

Comment: *В чем проблема?* А где собсно проблема-то?

Comment: /me вспоминает с ностальгией, как ещё совсем недавно на 200 пне гонял StarCraft первый...

Comment: Но я могу только 684 использовать из 3 GB не проблема?

Comment: @MahmudShahmuradov кто вам сказал что только 684? Как проверяли?

Comment: Диспетчер задач показывает 684.